# Update statement rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I have the following structure of json in db:

```
{   
   id: "dlsadas",
   code : {
      "312-43-1-3-v-d" : {
           contents : [
              {
                 "id" : 1 
              },
              {
                 "id" : 2
              }
           ]
      },
      "dbhwu-0dw-dw-dn" : {
           contents : [
              {
                 "id" : 5
              },
              {
                 "id" : 6
              }
           ]
      }
   }   
}
```

My question is :
How can i write an update statement so the **contents** array of key **312-43-1-3-v-d** gets the object **{id:8}** appended.

From what i have read i would have to do:

```
r.table('table').filter(...).update({code : {key: r.row(contents).append({id:8}) }})
```

But i cant.
Can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
r.table('table')
  .get('dlsadas')
  .update(function(doc) {
    return {code: {
      'dbhwu-0dw-dw-dn': {
        contents: doc('code')('dbhwu-0dw-dw-dn')('contents').append({id:8})
      }
    }};
  })
```

Or, perhaps consider changing your data format to something easier to work with - depending on your use cases.

Comment: tried but the 'dbhwu-0dw-dw-dn' is dynamic
and it only crashes if i do code[dynamic_key]["contents"] = doc(code)(dynamic_key)